# How to not refresh all AMP-Lists when calling setState()?

Tags: html, amp-html, amp-bind

I'm trying to set up an amp homepage using `amp-bind`.

I have this state JSON at the top of the page:

```
<amp-state id="myState" [src]="'/api/activity/all?country=' + selected">
  <script type="application/json">...
```

And I have these two AMP-Lists:

```
    <amp-list width="auto"
      height="192"
      layout="fixed-height"
      src="/api/activity/all"
      [src]="myState.categories"
      class="m1"
      id="categories"
      items="data.0.categories">

      <template type="amp-mustache">
         <amp-img  width="197" height="185" src="@{{icon}}"></amp-img>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
```

And this list:

```
      <amp-list width="auto"
        height="100"
        layout="fixed-height"
        src="/api/activity/all"
        [src]="myState.data"
        class="m1"
        id="activities"
        items="data">
```

So far so good. However, I Added a share button that shows an dropup menu when tapped. So I set up a toggler like this:

```
<amp-img on="tap:AMP.pushState({visible: !visible})" id="share-icon" alt="TO DO" width="50" height="50" src="design/share.png"></amp-img>
```

My issue is that when I tap the share button, though it works, it refreshes the two lists causing the to flicker.

Answer (score 0):

The flicker results from the amp-lists evaluating their binding (even if the `AMP.pushState(...)` call does not effect their bindings). Please file a bug report for the AMP Runtime [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).

Comment: I ended up using toggle visibility so not to touch states. But I went back to face the same issue with the like button. I need to see how to toggle hear-full and heart-empty classes without reliance on state.